# Xcode:scheme has no executable

Tags: xcode

When I create a new scheme, the "Executable" is "None". Does anyone know why?

[image: new scheme like this]

Comment: Does your project have any targets?

Comment: You should not create a new scheme. You should _duplicate_ an _existing_ scheme and then modify it. The chances of correctly making a new scheme from scratch are not high.